# Where to buy/How to build a Devanathan-Stachurski cell?

Tags: electrochemistry, hydrogen, diffusion

I'm preparing to do some hydrogen permeation tests to calculate the diffusivity of some iron samples. I would like to do this using the Devanathan-Stachurski cell, which consists of two cells, one where the hydrogen is charged and the other where it is oxidized (each containing an electrolyte solution), with the sample in the middle. The current produced by the diffusing hydrogen can be used to calculate diffusivity.

Does anyone have experience using this cell and know where to purchase one? So far I've only been able to find one company that sells it, but I would like to know about more options. If anyone has built it from scratch, can you provide some specifications on dimensions and materials used and how it worked for you?

Comment: I have searched this item, and I have found on: https://www.zimmerpeacocktech.com/products/accessories/devanathan-cell/ I have found with professor Cecílio SADAO Fugivara (UNESP) (email: sadao.fugivara@unesp.br) in Brazil too, that makes it on a considerable low price than the first option. About 400 dolars.

Comment: I found this website. They make Devanathan-Stachurski cells.
https://www.landtinst.com/product/devanathan-stachurski-cell-h-cell/ The price is around USD600.00. Looks like that they could do a lot of customization. Go check with it.

Comment: redox.me has so far the best Devanathan-Stachurski Permeation Cell available on the market.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you to do a research to find scientific articles on using DS cells. In this case if you have any specific questions you can try to contact authors directly, hopefully they will reply and be able to help you.

You can start from this article (Mike J. Danielson, *Corrosion Science* 2002 **44** (4), pp. 829-840) http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0010938X01001032. 
The author made his own DS cells as described follow [image]

Comment: Welcome on the Chemistry SE! Note, we prefer text copy-paste against screenshots. Screenshots are bad on multiple reasons, not only they are ugly but they are also far lesser indexed (if et al) and are practically not searchable/fixable/editable.

Answer (score 1):

I worked with Tyler, and something to add that I've recently found is doing a search for "H-type ion exchange membrane" cells or similar. An alternative would be to get 4" diameter recycled teflon rods from McMaster and machine them to suit your purposes as the main housing of each cell. A spherical ball joint clamp or threaded nylon rods could be used to secure the two cells together. The taller you make the cells and liquid height, the tighter the seal will need to be to prevent leaking.

Update 2020-05-28
I've been able to successfully 3D print and operate Devanathan cells. Mainly the chemical compatibility needs to be checked (e.g. by putting a cube of the 3D-printed material in the electrolyte and testing weight change after a day or so). For example, FormLab's Clear resin (e.g. Clear V2) is compatible with NaOH (I use 0.1 M NaOH) and seems to work just fine during the electrochemical tests. 3M has some teflon 3D printing services (not sure about cost), and other services like Xometry (not affiliated with either company) have some inexpensive chemically compatible materials that can be printed with (e.g. Ultem).

Answer (score 0):

(I wrote the question) - For those who still have this problem, I've found that the best way to prepare for this experiment is to talk with a glass blower. Most people who have done the experiment are vague in their details on how they made the cell, and the paper referenced above is the most detailed I have found. Many of the authors are also hard to get ahold of. I've found one supplier of the entire set-up, but it is a little pricey and would still have considerable lead-time for them to make (However if you'd like their info you can ask me separately). The more affordable method is to find a glassblower who can make it. They can make a hole/flange to turn a normal cell into an H-cell, and you need 2 of these for the experiment (or you can find 2 H-cells that work for your application if you can). Then you need O-rings to hold/seal your specimen in between and a way to clamp the flanges together. You also need to make sure you have enough entry ports for your electrodes and sparging if you choose to do that.

Short answer: This is not something that companies have in stock, and whether you make it yourself or hire someone else to make it, it requires considerable time and research to make sure you have all the details right.